# jax automatic differentiation

Tags: python, tensorflow, jax, automatic-differentiation

I have the following three functions implements in JAX.

```
def helper_1(params1):
   ...calculations...
   return z

def helper_2(z, params2):
   ...calculations...
   return y

def main(params1, params2):
   z = helper_1(params1)
   y = helper_2(z, params2)
   return z,y
```

I am interested in the partial derivatives of the output from main, i.e. `z` and `y`, with respect to both `params1` and `params2`. As `params1` and `params2` are low dimensional and `z` and `y` are high dimensional, I am using the jax.jacfwd function.

When calling

```
jax.jacfwd(main,argnums=(0,1))(params1,params2)
```

Jax computes the derivatives of `z` with respect to `params1` (and `params2`, which in this case is just a bunch of zeros). My question is: does Jax recompute dz/d_param1 for the derivatives of `y` with respect to `params1` and `params2`, or does it somehow figure out this has already been computed?

I don't know if this is relevant, but the 'helper_1' function contains functions from the TensorFlow library for Jax. Thanks!

Comment: the semantics of the question are incorrect becaue `return z` and `return y` do not exist as they were never created. `z` in the `helper_1` function is a different scope to `z` in the `main() fuction`. And the same is true for `y`.

Comment: if you provide a min reproducable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be easier to sow the answer....

Comment: hi @D.L 
thank you for your answers. I think the exact calculations through which z is defined inside `helper_1` function are not important, but just that it's a sequence of differentiable transformations. I am able to run the code and get the expected result. my issue is speed, and I suspect JAX computes the jacobian of z w.r.t `params_1` twice. is this enough information, or a minimal working example is still needed? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, in the situation you describe JAX's forward-mode autodiff approach will re-use the derivative of `z` when computing the derivative of `y`. If you wish, you can confirm this by looking at the [`jaxpr`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jaxpr.html) of your differentiated function:

```py
print(jax.make_jaxpr(jax.jacfwd(main, (0, 1)))(params1, params2))
```

Though if your function is more than moderately complicated, the output might be hard to understand.

As a general note, though, JAX's autodiff implementation does tend to produce a small number of unnecessary or duplicated computations. As a simple example consider this:

```py
import jax
print(jax.make_jaxpr(jax.grad(jax.lax.sin))(1.0))
# { lambda ; a:f32[]. let
#     _:f32[] = sin a
#     b:f32[] = cos a
#     c:f32[] = mul 1.0 b
#   in (c,) }
```

Here the primal value `sin(a)` is computed even though it is never used in computing the final output.

In practice this can be addressed by wrapping your computation in `jit`, in which case the XLA compiler takes care of optimization, including dead code elimination and de-duplication when applicable:

```py
result = jit(jax.jacfwd(main, (0, 1)))(params1, params2)
```